# Unable to print the array values in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, double

It's just a simple C program to display the array elements taken from the user but idk why am getting the garbage values when trying to print the array... if anyone could help i would really appreciate that... thanks!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double *array_dou;

double* initializeDoubles(int *maxdouble)
{

printf("Enter the max. double value the program should support: ");
scanf("%d",maxdouble);
array_dou = (double *) malloc((*maxdouble)*sizeof(double));
if(array_dou == NULL)                     
{
    printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
    exit(-1);
}

return array_dou;
}

int enterDouble(double *doubles,int dcount,int maxdouble)
{
 for(dcount=0; dcount<maxdouble; dcount++)
 {
printf("Please enter a double value: ");
scanf("%f",&doubles[dcount]);
 }
return dcount;
}

int main()
{
int maxdouble;

int dcount=0;

double *doubles;

doubles = initializeDoubles(&maxdouble);

dcount = enterDouble(doubles,dcount,maxdouble);

printf("\nDouble array\n");

for(int j=0;j<dcount;j++)
{
printf("%lf  ",doubles[j]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're only asking the user for one double, not N.

Comment: Also, `scanf("%f",&doubles[dcount]);` is wrong if `doubles` is an array of doubles; you want `%lf`.  (I didn't notice this myself, but my compiler did, and warned about it -- I wonder why yours didn't?)

Comment: you received just one doubles[0]. and use %lf instead of %f for double.

Comment: Please don't update the code when you've got already answers! If you remove code that an answer is commenting, then the answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling `enterDouble` only once and it reads only one value. Besides you are accessing the memory out of bounds. You allocated `dcount` number of elements, so you can access the memory only through the indices 0 to `dcount - 1`, yet you are passing `dcount` to `enterDouble`, thus you are trying to write at index `dcount` (one past the limit).

All other entries are uninitialized, so there you have two reasons why you see "garbage": the undefined behaviour of accessing memory out of bounds and the fact that you haven't initialized any of the doubles.

What you need to do is call `enterDouble` for all indices:

```
for(int j = 0; j < dcount; ++i)
    enterDouble(doubles, j);
```

And the `dcount++;` in `enterDouble` makes to me no sense, the caller knows which index it it passing, no need to returns the same index + 1.

Also see [do not cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and you are not freeing the memory you've
allocated.

Also the proper conversion specifier for reading doubles with `scanf` is `%lf`, not `%f`.

> *man scanf*
>
> ...
>
> **`l`**      Indicates  either  that  the conversion will be one of `d, i, o, u, x, X`, or `n` and the next pointer is a pointer to a `long int` or
>   `unsigned long in` (rather than `int`), or that the conversion will be one of `e, f`, or `g` and **the next pointer is a pointer to
>   `double` (rather than `float`).**
>
> ...
>
> **`f`**      Matches an optionally signed floating-point number; the next pointer must be a pointer to `float`.